# gridview material design in android studio

Tags: android

I have a problem

See the image

[image]

I want such a picture

[image]

My experience

custom layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >




                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/car" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.wallpaper.MainActivity">


    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

list adapter

```
package com.example.user.wallpaper;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class list_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<Integer> list_photo;
    ArrayList<String> list_title;


    public list_adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Integer> list_photo, ArrayList<String> list_title) {
        super(activity, R.layout.custom,list_title);

        this.activity=activity;
        this.list_photo=list_photo;
        this.list_title=list_title;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater= activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom,parent,false);
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(list_photo.get(position));
        return v;
    }
}
```

main activity

```
package com.example.user.wallpaper;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Integer> list_photo  = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list_title  = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        list_photo.add(R.drawable.car);
        list_photo.add(R.drawable.mta);
        list_photo.add(R.drawable.car);




        list_title.add("#FF1E7DA9");
        list_title.add("#FF1E7DA9");
        list_title.add("#FF1E7DA9");





        GridView lv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        list_adapter ad = new list_adapter(MainActivity.this,list_photo,list_title);
        lv.setAdapter(ad);

    }
}
```

I hope dont ignored me please help me :(

Comment: You want  a RecyclerView and a GridLayoutManager

Comment: you have video tutorial?